# Paginator django с преходом на страницы

Tags: django, pagination

На сайте стоит встроенный пагинатор django, хочу сделать не простой переход по страницам (назад и вперед), а с небольшим выбором страницы (как тут http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination ). Но не знаю как проверить доступность n (не след) страницы и как сделать чтобы это адекватно работало. 
ps те вывод не всех страниц, а налево 2 и направо 2 (как в гугле или яндексе)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению вам придётся написать свой собственный пагинатор (или воспользоваться имеющимися сниппетами), готового компонента я не находил.

Сама идея достаточно проста - вам просто надо посчитать сколько страниц нужно вывести вокруг текущей страницы и достаточно ли страниц, чтобы вывести страницы вначале и страницы в конце списка.

Всё это можно оформить прямо в вёрстке в шаблоне, но по опыту скажу, что получается очень громоздко. Лучше написать templatetag ([или воспользоваться готовым](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/73/)). Если же позволяет навык владения питоном, то можно написать собственный пагинатор (или же взять [готовый сниппет](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/773/)).

Можно также поискать в англоязычной части интернета, там это называют "fraction paginator", "digg-like paginator". Ну и вот напоследок неплохая [статья на эту тему](https://www.tummy.com/articles/django-pagination/)

Comment: Спасибо, не думал то что через несколько месяцев ответят.

Answer (score 3):

Можно на переделывать стандартный пагинатор.
Переходы на начало/конец и назад/вперед вполне понятно как сделать уже после прочтения [стандартной документации](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/pagination.html).

Если надо вывести ссылки на все страницы, то делаем итерации по `p.page_range`

Для решения же Вашей задачи, требуется рассчитать "окно", которое будет перемещаться по списку всех страниц в зависимости от текущей страницы.
И надо будет использовать в шаблоне не весь `p.page_range`, а итератор по этому "окну". Назовем его `my_page_range`.

Так же нужна константа, которая будет хранить количество страниц, видимых слева и справа от текущей. Назовем ее `ADD_PAGES`.
Нужно учесть, что в "крайних точках" количество страниц слева и справа от текущей не равно друг другу.

Используем пример из документации, добавив в него необходимые изменения:

```
...
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    contacts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

# --- наш добавляемый код ---

ADD_PAGES = 2  # количество страниц слева и справа от текущей 
# таким образом, все "окно" состоит из 5 страниц, включая текущую 

if contacts.paginator.num_pages > ADD_PAGES * 2 + 1:
# количество страниц больше чем "окно"

    # найдем начало и конец "окна" для общего случая
    start_window = contacts.number - ADD_PAGES
    end_window = contacts.number + ADD_PAGES

    if start_window < 1:
    # если "окно вылезает" за левую границу
        # то левую границу ставим на 1-ю страницу
        start_window = 1
        # а правую границу вычисляем относительно 1-й
        end_window = 1 + ADD_PAGES * 2

    if end_window > contacts.paginator.num_pages:
    # если "окно вылезает" за правую границу
        # то правую границу ставим на последнюю страницу
        end_window = contacts.paginator.num_pages
        # а левую границу вычисляем относительно последней страницы
        start_window = end_window - ADD_PAGES * 2

    # определим итератор для "окна"
    my_page_range = range(start_window, end_window + 1)

else:
# количество страниц меньше или равно "окну"
    # просто используем весь диапазон доступных страниц, т.е. page_range
    my_page_range = contacts.paginator.page_range
```

Теперь осталось передать в шаблон `my_page_range` и пройтись там по нему в цикле когда "рисуете" кнопки пагинатора.